# searching for duplicates

Tags: vba, replace, userform

I presently have a UserForm that feeds into a spreadsheet. I require that once the information is entered into the UserForm that a search is done within the spreadsheet for rows that match the same PRI, if so the previous information is deleted and the new information populated in the sheet. It is important that only the matching PRI numbers are removed and if the new submission as additional options than the previous it doesn't overwrite other rows. This is my present coding:

```
 Private Sub CmdAdd_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim info
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim n As Long
    Dim r As Range

 Const strPwd As String = "Transfer19"

 ThisWorkbook.Unprotect Password:=strPwd

 Set ws = Worksheets("Inventory")

With ws

'get all the tombstone info into an array
info = Array(Me.TxtFirst.Value, Me.TxtLast.Value, _
            Me.TxtPRI.Value, Me.TxtGR.Value, _
            Me.TxtLV.Value, Me.TxtLinguistic.Value, _
            Me.TxtEmail.Value, Me.TxtResumeNum.Value, _
            Me.TxtReason.Value, Me.TxtDate.Value)

.Unprotect Password:="Transfer19"

'get the first empty row...
Set rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow

'loop over the province and city controls
For n = 1 To 10
     'get province and city values
     p = Me.Controls("ListProv" & n).Value
     c = Me.Controls("ListCity" & n).Value

    If n = 1 Or p <> "" Then
        rw.Cells(1).Resize(1, 10).Value = info
        rw.Cells(11).Value = p
        rw.Cells(12).Value = c
        Set rw = rw.Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Next n

.Protect Password:="Transfer19"

End With

ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:=strPwd

ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

This is what I tried which partially works. It finds the duplicates and replaces with the new information but it doesn't work with the present loop

```
 'searching for duplicates
  Set r = ws.Range("C:C").Find(Me.TxtPRI.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
              If Not r Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Duplicate entry. The record is deleted and the new data is placed"
    iRow = r.Row
End If
```

Comment: What did you already try?  There are dozens of questions here on SO about deleting rows which match a criteria, so maybe start by looking at those, then post back with what you tried and the problem you ran into (of course it may just work, in which case feel free to post that as an answer)   https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+delete+rows

Comment: Additionally, it sounds like there possibility exists that a PRI might be duplicated multiple times. Do you want to remove all duplicated PRI values, and replace them once with the new information? Or do you want to replace each of the duplicated PRI values with the new information?

Comment: Without a lot more code to manage resolving matches, it would be simplest to remove all the existing rows, and add new rows to the end of the table.

Comment: see what I tried above

Comment: I agree @TimWilliams. Unless he simply wants to overwrite each instance with the new data, in which case there is no deletion to worry about.

Comment: @excelrookie since  i've discovered the synergy between `arrays` and Dictionaries I am a fan. You could beforehand input your worksheet data into one array `arrData = ws.Range("C:C").Value` and then loop through adding all the values into a dictionary. then your code to look for duplicates would be `If DictDuplicates.Exists(Me.TxtPRI.Value) Then...` this way is way faster than finding everytime on the worksheet what you are supposed  to because dictionaries have the keys indexed and there is no need to loop through to find the item for each key (in this case, they key could be the row number).

Comment: All you need to do is create a standalone sub to which you pass a PRI, which then deletes all existing rows with that same PRI.  Call that just before you insert the new rows.

Comment: @Tim.... thanks Tim. Prior to creating the loop that you helped me with. I had the coding that would search for duplicates (see above) but I am unable to adapt it to the coding (loop) that you showed me. Can you provide some assistance with that?